# jQuery columnize crashes when setting height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jquery columnizer plugin to create columns of a text in a div. The used plugin can be found [here](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Below is an example of my html which should be divided into three columns:

```
    <div class="textColumn">    
        <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum adipiscing,
nisi tempus tincidunt tempor, lorem libero venenatis lectus, molestie congue arcu risus ut
lorem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mauris lorem, eleifend
vitae auctor id, rhoncus eget mi. Nunc convallis condimentum pretium. Praesent vulputate
mauris sit amet nisl porttitor fringilla. Aliquam sit amet venenatis risus. Nullam
malesuada hendrerit dolor, id sagittis libero condimentum non. Sed dapibus bibendum augue,
id lobortis arcu iaculis laoreet. Maecenas lacinia mattis ipsum, ut vehicula nulla
tristique id. Quisque vehicula orci vitae nibh ultricies ac dictum metus pretium. Donec id
arcu tellus, vulputate blandit augue. Integer turpis felis, cursus et congue sit amet,
mollis at neque. Nunc pellentesque erat vel odio tempus aliquam.<br>
    <br>
    Quisque faucibus lectus luctus odio blandit aliquet. Phasellus blandit augue vel eros
lacinia nec hendrerit ligula sagittis. Sed sollicitudin ultricies sem sit ametpellentesque.
Fusce semper purus vel massa porttitor vestibulum. Fusce eget erat eu augue ullamcorper
mattis. Morbi adipiscing fermentum purus, ut ultrices libero tristique sed. Fusce ut augue
in ante rhoncus iaculis. Nunc auctor, est sit amet ornare dictum, dolor odio elementum 
orci, vitae porta enim nisi id felis. Aenean justo mauris, fringilla id faucibus eget,
tincidunt ornare purus. Aenean dapibus sapien non justo elementum sollicitudin. In at
vehicula turpis. Sed porta rhoncus arcu a cursus. Maecenas eu purus in urna mattis ornare
et et arcu. Suspendisse auctor magna ac tortor condimentum condimentum.<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In a generic javascript file i've defined a document.ready function in which in executing the columnizer to create my columns. This is done with the javascript below. It works fine when defining only a width. However, I also want to set a limited height for the columns. As soon as I do this the plugin (and there with also the browser) crashes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content.one .textColumn .text').columnize({
            width: 169
            /*,height: 162*/    /*Enabling this rule crashes the internet!*/
    });
});
```

I've tried with the width and height both setup, but also with only the height setup. Both make the plugin crash. Also defining the height inside the plugin (and therewith modifying the plugin) make it crash. According to [this jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/columnize) page it should be possible to set a height and also [this example](http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample5.html) shows a working version.

Does anyone have a good resolution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the plugin, please use this one:
https://raw.github.com/cioddi/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/71eae2c531419274a1ec085f6a6485038e98c9f3/src/jquery.columnizer.js

I got it from a git push request. Your js code is valid. please see this jsfiddle as prove: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kxMJM/

I got the patched plugin from [cioddi](https://github.com/cioddi/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin/commit/71eae2c531419274a1ec085f6a6485038e98c9f3#diff-0)